# Getting all excel cells of a particular color

Tags: python, excel, colors, automation, com

I am automating a particular piece in this test harness. One of the pieces includes that data gets populated into excel cells of a particular color. Can I use UsedRange.Find instead of a for loop iterator to search for cells of that color? I really don't want to loop through every cell and do a cell.interior.colorindex, rather an optimal query. The language I am using is python and because I am in a testing tool IDE, I don't have access to xlrd. So this is all COM.

Answer (score 0):

**Update!**
<s>Yes, you may use `sheets(..).usedrange.find ...`!</s>
I could not reproduce the `sheets(..).usedrange.find` result today!

**Below a (reduced and corrected) vba code example:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Find_Yellow()
    Dim firstFind As Range
    Dim iCt As Integer
    For iCt = 1 To 2
        If iCt = 1 Then Range("C15").Interior.Color = -4142 'xlNone   = -4142
        If iCt = 2 Then Range("C15").Interior.Color = 65535 'vbyellow = 65535
        Call SetInteriorSearchColor(65535) 'vbyellow = 65535
        Set firstFind = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
            Set firstFind = Sheets(1).Cells.Find("", Cells(1, 1), -4123, 2, 1, 1, False, , True)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If firstFind Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print "round " & iCt & ": Yellow filled cell NOT found!"
        Else
            Debug.Print "round " & iCt & ": Yellow filled cell found at " & firstFind.Address & "!"
        End If
    Next iCt
End Sub

Sub SetInteriorSearchColor(IscColor As Long)
    With Application.FindFormat.Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = IscColor 'vbyellow = 65535 'orange = 49407
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

**immediate window**

```
round 1: Yellow filled cell NOT found!
round 2: Yellow filled cell found at $C$15!
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that! I tried replicating in python so...

ws = wb.WorkSheets.Item[sheetname]
used = ws.UsedRange
Excel.Application.FindFormat.Interior.Color = 15849925

firstfind = used.Find("",ws.Cells.Item[1,1],-4123,2,1,1,False,True)

Unfortunately I wasn't getting the cell I wanted but it just went to Cell 1,2! Do you think I am entering the incorrect parameters? I can't use MS enumerators explcitly so I have to use numbers instead. Will this work if the overall approach work even if the sheet is protected?

Comment: There is a parameter "MatchByte" after "MatchCase". Next one is Searchformat then!

Comment: Try: ws.cells.Find("",ws.Cells.Item[1,1],-4123,2,1,1,False,,True)

Comment: OMG IT WORKED. If you were here I would buy you a beer.

Comment: Nice! Good to hear!